# unable to delete entry from ldap database

Tags: ldap

I have a problem deleting an entry from a ldap database.

`sudo slapcat -b dc=example,dc=com`

shows an entry:

```
dn: cn=Kopieren von autan,ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: automount
automountInformation: -fstype=nfs,nodev,nosuid autan.example.com:/work
cn: Kopieren von autan
structuralObjectClass: automount
entryUUID: 5282655a-5a04-103a-8ad0-abf441f88777
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
createTimestamp: 20200714095833Z
entryCSN: 20200714095833.486437Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=mexample,dc=com
modifyTimestamp: 20200714095833Z
```

I want to get rid of it, but the attempts I try fail.

```
user@host:~>sudo ldapdelete -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W "cn=Kopieren von autan,ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com"
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_delete: No such object (32)
    matched DN: ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com
```

I tried it as well with a ldif file and ldapmodify.

del_autan.ldif:

```
dn: cn=Kopieren von autan,ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: delete
```

and than

```
user@host:~> sudo ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f del_autan.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
deleting entry "cn=Kopieren von autan,ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_delete: No such object (32)
    matched DN: ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com
```

Intersting thing is, that tools like jxplorer do not show the entry, but it appears in the automounter.

Comment: What if you use ldapsearch to view everything under ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com? Also, try the following:
sudo ldapdelete -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W "cn=Kopieren%20von%20autan,ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com"
or
sudo ldapdelete -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W 'cn="Kopieren von autan",ou=auto.work,ou=autofs,dc=example,dc=com'

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your suggestion. I tried both resulting in "ldap_delete: No such object (32)".